# Create Stylus variable with several classes and concatenate in compilation

Tags: css, compilation, stylus

I'm in the situation that I want to assign the same CSS rules to several selectors and normally I use [Stylus interpolation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html#selector-interpolation) assigning several classes to a variable.

```
pages = '.home, .about, .contact'

{pages}
    a
        color black
```

This yields in:

```
.home a, .about a, .contact a {
    color: black;
}
```

But I have an issue that I would like to resolve in an elegant way if it would be possible. Let's say now I want to use the same variable to concatenate with another one, for example:

```
.general
    &{pages}
        a
            background-color black
```

This yields in the expected way:

```
.general.home a, .general .about a, .general .contact a {
    background-color: black;
}
```

I would like to generate a "double class" selector in each case, not only the first one. For this I have tried to use an iteration method that works, but I'm not satisfied at all:

```
pages = home about contact

.general
    for class in pages
        &.{class}
            a
                color black
```

This yields in:

```
.general.home a { color: black; }
.general.about a { color: black; }
.general.contact a { color: black; }
```

This is not too bad, but when I want to use the same variable in the first way (this is the most common use that I give to this variables), I can't because it's not compiling with the correct selector syntax.

Can you think of any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ended creating two types of variables for each group of classes and using the one I need in each situation. 
`pages = '.home, .about, .contact'`
`pagesArray = home about contact`
But I don't like this solution at all because it's more difficult to maintain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `&` to every class in the string of selectors:

```
pages = '&.home, &.about, &.contact'

.general
  {pages}
    a
      color black
```

Even automatically with `replace` bif:

```
pages = '.home, .about, .contact'

.general
  {replace('\.', '&.', pages)}
    a
      color black
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very clean.

Comment: Is it possible to add more variables with commas? There is example of what I'm asking... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBoLRZ In literal CSS there is the result I would like to achieve... Thanks for your help!